Why is there no 'that' before 'meets' in 'more than meets the eye'?
Like, it seems to be more grammatical to say,

There's more to his personality than that meets the eye.

By the way, since we see it with both our eyes, why is 'eye' in its singular form in the expression?

nb, "meat" vs "meet"

Your version is not quite there, it could/should be: "There is more than that which meets the eye”

There's a lot that's "weird" about this construction, so let's look at one that's built the same way but easier to think about.

There are more people here than fit in this car.

Given this sentence, your question might be "Why don't we say 'There are more people here than that fit in this car?'"
First, we just can't use "that" that way. We could throw in a few more words, like "... than those that fit in this car." But ultimately we don't have to because we're reusing "people" to apply not only to "are" but to "fit." Or, really, we're saying "There are more people here than the number of people that fit."
Now, things get a little weirder in your example because "There's more to his personality..." More what? What's the actual noun here?* What is there more of? It doesn't say. But whatever it is, there's more of it. And whatever it is, some amount of it meets the eye, and whatever amount that is... there's more than that.
As for why "eye" is singular, shrug, idioms are weird sometimes. It's pretty common in such idioms about sight, though, like "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder." It seems to be true even from ancient times; in the Gospel of Matthew Jesus says "The eye is the lamp of the body," and the original Greek is singular. Maybe it's so one can speak in a parallel way? The heart, the head, the eye, the hand?
* If we're going to answer this question seriously, "more" functions as the noun. But we know what we mean—it stands for some unspoken quality.
